# How to detect when a Form is being dragged?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, drag-and-drop

I have a Form object with a title bar displayed.

I need a pure managed way(P/Invoke-free, both Mono and .NET compatible, preferrably a .NET 2.0 API) to detect when the **FORM** itself starts being dragged, changes location and when it is dropped(not any content).

I did this in the past in Mono but I don't remember how anymore and I don't know if my solution was MS.NET-compatible...

If anyone could provide an example, three event names for me to google more details or point me to a relevant StackOverflow question, I would greatly appreciate. So far, my search has returned no relevant results...

Comment: @luiscubal: "pure unmanaged way" - do you mean "pure managed way"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you talking actual drag-drop operation here, or when the user moves the form? If it is the movement itself, you might be able to use the [`ResizeBegin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.resizebegin.aspx) event, which is raised when the user starts to move the form. This together with [`LocationChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.locationchanged.aspx) and [`ResizeEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.resizeend.aspx) should cover your needs. However, the `ResizeBegin` and `ResizeEnd` events are (of course) also raised when you start and end resizing the form, not only when you are moving it.

Comment: This, along with "Move" event, seems to be what I needed.